# Как ускорить работу Apps Script в Google Sheets средствами Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud, gcp

В Google Spreadsheets создал меню, из меню перехожу по листам (около 60 листов).
При переходе на лист начинает работать скрипт именно для этого листа.
Скрипт протягивает формулу G7:G500 на каждом листе.
Когда в ячейки получаю результат формулы, применяю метод getValue() и заполняю тот же диапазон G7:G500 setValue().

**При переходе на третий или четвертый лист, начинает подвисать и перестает работать.**

Смотрел в сторону default и standard project.
Смотрел в сторону квот и ограничений.

Предложите в какую сторону смотреть?
Нужно получить бесперебойную производительность в таблицах Google!
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Каждое  обращение к листу жрет ресурсы. Бэст практисом  предполагаются редкие (только вынужденные) обращения  к листу. Т.е. Вы cначала забираете входящие данные с диапазона (Range) листа, например, A7:F500 в массив одним getValues(), рассчитываете формулой внутри скрипта выходные значения и помещаете их в массив ResultArray из 494 элементов, а затем одним setValues() вставляете этот массив в диапазон

```
.getRange('G7:G500').setValues(ResultArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то эту задачу через Sheets API можно решить в 2 запроса:

- [get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) получить всю Таблицу
- [update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) записать изменения

По крайней мере это будет работать для независимых (относительно положения на листах) формул.

Sheets API работает через Advanced Services в самих скриптах.